# select id by the min and max (sql)

Tags: mysql, sql, select, max, min

List the id and discount percentage of customers who have the largest discount

and those who have the smallest discount.

Comment: Can you please try to explain a bit more detailed what you want to achieve? How does your table look like (maybe give a small example table)? Right now it is hard to understand what you are asking for.

Comment: I am sorry , and thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the MAX() and MIN() function to get the ids having largest and the id having smallest discount.

```
Select id,discount
from customer 
where discount=(select MAX(discount) from customer) OR discount=(select MIN(discount) from customer);
```

Comment: thank you so much for answer but you forget so select the discount because it say list id and discount

Comment: you must know this small thing. Moreover if you are not able to upvote my answar, you should not downvote for this silly mistake@hadel...thanks

Comment: I am really sorry this is my first time here and  I did this by mistake I did not know what are this for I thought it is for going down and up . sorry again